# Apollo client expects fewer response items than the server is returning

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

After migrating to Apollo client 3 from 1 I started receiving errors due to debug response item, that my server is passing. The client expects one less element than arrives. Errors look like this:

```
ApolloError: server returned results with length 3, expected length of 2
    at new ApolloError (index.js:26:1)
    at QueryManager.js:668:1
    at both (asyncMap.js:16:1)
    at asyncMap.js:9:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.then (asyncMap.js:9:1)
    at Object.error (asyncMap.js:17:1)
    at notifySubscription (module.js:137:1)
    at onNotify (module.js:176:1)
    at SubscriptionObserver.error (module.js:229:1)
```

How can I allow more response items than expected?

I need to ignore the last item if there are more items in response than expected. I tried parsing responses in custom fetch, but in that case, I should resolve a data stream and the next consumers can't use it.